# SQL Query which deletes an attribute in XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have column of XML type.There's a xml like this

```
<items>
   <item type="xxx"><items>
   <item type="xxx"><items>
</items>
```

I need to delete all type attributes. I know oracle has some functions for xml manipulation, but I don't get how to delete attributes.

How would such query look like ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example using the Oracle supplied SQL function [deletexml](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions042.htm#SQLRF06202)

**Acknowledgement to Jonas Lincoln as I am using his XPATH expression**

```
SELECT deleteXML(xmltype.CREATEXML('<items>
                                       <item type="xxx">a</item>
                                       <item type="xxx">b</item>
                                   </items>'),
                                   '/items/item[@type="xxx"]/@type')
FROM dual  

<items>
   <item>a</item>
   <item>b</item>
</items>
```

Comment: +1 one for an answer that targets Oracle instead of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @xml as xml
set @xml = '
<items>
    <item type="xxx">3</item>
    <item type="xxx">4</item>
    </items>'

SET @xml.modify('delete (/items/item[@type="xxx"]/@type)')

select cast(@xml as nvarchar(100))

<items>
  <item>3</item>
  <item>4</item>
</items>
```

Comment: How to remove the xmlns, xmlns:xsi and xsi:schemaLocation atrribute from document_list tag ........<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<document_list xmlns="http://www.w3sools.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.montfund.com/xsd/msf_file_x_data.xsd" 
source_system_name="ECDFRI" target_system_name="Extract">